# Достижимый,постижимый - какие это причастия?

Tags: грамматика

В русской грамматике, как известно, нет причастий будущего времени.  Тем не менее, в речи они все же встречаются. Как быть с причастиями, вынесенными в заголовок? Можно ли их отнести к причастиям будущего времени? И как вы думаете, могут ли составители грамматик узаконить причастия будущего времени?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В одном из ответов в этой теме прозвучало:

> **сделающий… откроющего…** Не надо эти формы называть причастиями будущего
>   времени, это просто **причастия настоящего времени** с расширенными
>   функциями, обозначающие сдвиг по времени для ситуации, отнесенной к
>   будущему времени.

По-моему, автор этого ответа забыл о том, что от глаголов совершенного вида (***что сделать?*** -- *сделать, открыть*) причастия настоящего времени не образуются. А вот причастия будущего времени… а почему бы и нет?

Из книги Милославского И.Г. *"Морфологические категории современного русского языка"* (М., 2011):

> У глаголов совершенного вида существуют только причастия прошедшего
>   времени. Причастия настоящего времени у этих глаголов отсутствуют.
>   **Иногда, хотя и крайне редко, встречаются причастия будущего времени**: *приедущий из столицы* (Гоголь), *не увидящая ни балов, ни
>   театров* (Писемский).

Не противоречит Милославскому и автор энциклопедического словаря-справочника *"Морфология русского языка"* Г.И. Панова:

> Отсутствие у прич. форм буд. времени обусловлено традицией, а не
>   логически (не потому, что семантика прич. несовместима с морф.
>   значением буд. времени). Поэтому, когда говорящий ощущает потребность
>   в образовании этих словоформ, он их образует.

Когда подобные словоформы будут признаны нормативными, не знаю. На мой взгляд, вполне нормально звучат причастия буд. времени от глаголов ***сделать (сделающий), суметь (сумеющий), прочитать (прочитающий)***  и многих других.

Что же до слов ***достижимый, постижимый…***  Они, по-моему, могут быть и прилагательными, и причастиями. К примеру, здесь --

> *Для человеческого разума познание истины, как обретение непререкаемой достоверности, решительно недоступно, и единственный
>   **достижимый им** [т. е. разумом] **результат**, это — скептическое еросhе, воздержание от всякого утверждения*

-- имеем, на мой взгляд, явное причастие: дополнение ***им*** указывает на наличие у формы ***достижимый*** страдательного залога, что свойственно именно причастиям, но никак не прилагательным.

Comment: 1) "Поэтому, когда говорящий ощущает потребность в образовании этих словоформ, он их образует". Остается только определить, когда возникает эта "физиологическая" потребность. 2)  Причастия на МЫЙ обозначают признак действия, совпадающего с действием глагола-сказуемого, формальный Т.п. здесь задачу не решает. Приведите пример такого предложения с причастием, образованным от глагола СВ.

Answer (score 3):

1) Серж, достижимый и постижимый - это прилагательные, так как они образованы от глаголов совершенного вида.

Да и почти все формы на МЫЙ - это прилагательные, причастиями они считаются при наличии следующих условий: образование от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида + наличие зависимого слова в Т.п., обозначающего производителя действия или орудие действия, например: видимый мною корабль.

**Только в этом случае слово обозначает реально происходящее в данный момент действие.**

2) Достижимый - это тот, которого можно достичь, здесь нет никакого происходящего во времени  действия, только обозначение возможности этого действия.

3) К будущему времени можно отнести только краткие причастия в составе составного именного сказуемого: цель будет достигнута.

Comment: *так как они образованы от глаголов совершенного вида* - Vera, Господь с Вами. Разве глаголы совершенного вида не могут образовывать причастий? Вы сильно запутались. –

Comment: [Михаил Эйнштейн. Причастия будущего времени](http://www.emory.edu/INTELNET/prich_bud.htm). Вера, автор этой статьи утверждает, что это причастия будущего времени. Прочитайте, пожалуйста, статью.

Comment: Фамилия автора ЭПштейн. Статья имеет право на существование, но в ней так всё спорно...

Comment: Екатерина, а что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: Сотворимый мир в нём скрыт.  Что это по-вашему - прилагательное или причастие?

Comment: behemothus, речь идет о глагольных формах на МЫЙ, то есть страдательные причастия прошедшего времени образуются ТОЛЬКО от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида (дословная цитата из современной грамматики для вузов (2009).  Вы, кстати,  всегда очень эмоциональны и любите делать поспешные оценочные выводы. Я бы сказала, неосторожны в своих выводах.

Comment: Серж, я буду тщательно изучать статью уважаемого Михаила Наумовича, большое Вам спасибо за ссылку, но его выводы пока вызывают сомнения. Возможно, я отвечу Вам позже.

Answer (score 1):

О СТАТЬЕ

1) Время для причастий (как и для деепричастий) – это вещь относительная, так как причастия обозначают  не время действия, а его СООТНЕСЕННОСТЬ со временем  действия глагола-сказуемого.

2) Сейчас действительные причастия настоящего времени  определяются как обозначающие признак, развивающийся ОДНОВРЕМЕННО с действием глагола-сказуемого:   Я смотрю на птиц, летящих на юг. Я смотрел на птиц, летящих на юг. Я буду смотреть на птиц, летящих на юг.

3) Можно провести эксперимент и  добавить им еще одну функцию – обозначение  признака действия, закончившегося в будущем ранее действия основного глагола: придущий, напищущий, смогущий и др. Эти формы  прежде регулярно встречались в литературе, а теперь подверглись запрету. А почему?

4) Если вопрос касается СУБЪЕКТА действия, то использование этих форм является ИЗБЫТОЧНЫМ, например:  «Человек, сумеющий преодолеть все препятствия, достигнет многого. Человек, сумевший преодолеть все препятствия, достигнет многого».  Завершенность действия здесь можно обозначить причастием прошедшего времени, и, может быть, поэтому формы стали считаться устаревшими.

5) Но если это касается ОБЪЕКТА действия, то СМЫСЛ В ЭТОМ ЕСТЬ, так как без этих причастий, действительно, не обойтись, например: В  аэропорту поставят новый сканер, сделающий личный досмотр пассажиров ненужным.    Современная наука ждет нового Эйнштейна, откроющего единый закон всех четырех физических взаимодействий.

6) Только не надо эти формы называть причастиями будущего времени, это просто причастия настоящего времени с расширенными функциями, обозначающие сдвиг по времени для ситуации, отнесенной к будущему времени.

7) Что касается статьи, то автор, к сожалению,   НЕ ОБОЗНАЧИЛ ОБЛАСТЬ ПРИМЕНЕНИЯ СВОИХ ПРИЧАСТИЙ, а без этого его доводы у читателей вызывают сомнение и не кажутся вполне убедительными.

Comment: Вера, но ведь причастия будущего времени были в русском. Да, ясно, что время для причастий - вещь относительная. Я  не совсем понимаю: область применения.  Вы относите ''откроющего'' к настоящему времени. Получается, что для глагола открыть есть сразу две формы причастий: открывающего и откроющего.

Comment: Открывать - открывающего, открыть - откроющего. Область применения я обозначила: для субъекта действия  такая форма избыточная и ненужная, для объекта - нужная и реально существующая.  Не надо было  автору смешивать разные ситуации.

Comment: Вера, без причастия получится ''сумеющий" получится констатация факта,  в то время как  причастие "сумеющий"  выражает потенциальность действия. Поэтому говорить об избыточности считаю не совсем правильно.

Comment: Какая констатация факта, если речь идет о будущем времени? Сумевший преодолеть, сумеющий преодолеть или тот, который сумеет преодолеть - я не вижу  между ними принципиальной разницы. Что касается причастия, отнесенного к объекту, то там подходит единственный вариант "сделающий, откроющий".

Comment: Вера, здесь не совсем ясно: сумевший  эквивалентно  будущему, после момента высказывания, или прошлому, до момента высказывания.

Comment: Говорящий описывает ситуацию относительно глагола "достигнет", именно это важно, а не момент речи. Может быть,  лишние временные указатели , напротив,  даже затеняют основной смысл.

Comment: Вера, я согласен. Важно не только, что он достигнет, но и когда он достигнет. Читатель может подумать, что автор достиг уже чего-то в прошлом.

Comment: Серж, в данном предложении  причинно-следственная связь, поэтому важна только последовательность событий: если сумеет, то достигнет. Важна законченность первого действия, а не конкретное время его завершения.

Comment: Вера, да, я прочитал невнимательно. Но все же. Ведь не всегда причастие будущее можно заменить причастием прошедшего времени. В статье есть примеры, когда может возникнуть двусмысленность.

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что не всегда. Наша официальная грамматика не очень внимательна к языку, часто вопрос решаются формально, без должного их понимания.

Comment: Ирина Левонтина( доктор филологических наук) считает, например, что, возможно, когда-нибудь лингвисты узаконят причастие будущего времени.

Answer (score 1):

Де-юре, причастия будущего времени и сейчас узаконены. В Викисловаре в словарном гнезде "быть" есть табличка, показывающая спряжение этого глагола. В этой табличке есть строка: причастие будущего времени, и напротив написаны слова: будущий, будущая, будущее, будущие. То есть, признаётся только одно причастие будущего времени: будущий. Де-факто,  причастия будущего времени отсутствуют. В учебниках русского языка, в Википедии и во многих других источниках указано, что будущего времени у причастий не бывает. Я считаю, что узаконить такие причастия могут, правда, этому мешает их очень малое количество.

Comment: Спор именно в том, что такие причастия потенциально возможны. Но вопрос, когда эти причастия узаконят - неизвестно.

Answer (score 0):

Это не причастия будущего времени. Это обычные страдательные причастия настоящего времени (они же  - отглагольные прилагательные), несколько устаревшая форма у первого, второе вполне активно.

При этом в сейчас качестве причастий чаще используются современные синонимы - типа "постигаемый", но они есть не у всех глаголов и они не могут стать отглагольными прилагательными. Поэтому "достижимый" и "постижимый" чаще классифицируют как прилагательные, но это не отнимает у них права быть одновременно и причастиями.

Причастия будущего времени окказионально образуются от глаголов совершенного вида типа "придущий", "напишущий" и т.д.

> Так вот что ожидает немцев, сейчас пойдущих в атаку, чтобы раздавить
>   один-единственный несчастный эскадрон.

(Гумилев, "Записки артиллериста")