# Причастия будущего времени

Tags: грамматика

Согласно академической науке, причастий будущего времени в русском языке нет и не может быть. Однако они есть! Примеры: добьющийся, полюбящий, сбегущий, ***предъявящий*** (см. у Н.В.Гоголя), узрящий, нальющий, вздыбящийся и целый ряд других. Они образуются от глаголов совершенного вида (добиться, полюбить, сбежать...) при помощи суффиксов -ущ-(-ющ-)/-ащ-(-ящ-) и при условии благозвучия используются в публицистике, сетевом дискурсе, литературе (где нет *строгой редактуры*).
Как вы относитесь к таким причастиям? Есть ли у них будущее и надежда на официальное включение в литературный русский язык?

Comment: ЧБ отметился, кнопку надавил)))

Comment: [Интересное обсуждение и здесь. Причастие](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416950/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Хотел написать в ответе, а почему-то пришло сюда.

Answer (score 7):

> Согласно академической науке, причастий будущего времени в русском
>   языке нет и не может быть... **Есть ли у них будущее и надежда на
>   официальное включение в литературный русский язык?**

По-моему, какие-то шаги в этом направлении уже делаются.

Из учебника для вузов под ред. Дибровой Е.И. (В.В. Бабайцева, Н.А. Николина, В.С. Печникова и др. 
***"Современный русский язык. Теория. Анализ языковых единиц. В 2 частях. Часть 2. Морфология. Синтаксис"***, 4-е изд., М., 2011):

> Будущего времени у причастий нет, как это отмечается в учебных
>   пособиях и научных грамматиках. **Однако в современном русском языке
>   наблюдается тенденция к образованию причастий с суффиксами *-ущ, -ющ,
>   -ащ, -ящ, -ем, -им*** от глаголов совершенного вида: ***откроющийся*** (открыться), ***потребующийся*** (потребоваться), ***взволнующий***
>   (взволновать). Как отмечают исследователи, число таких употреблений
>   растёт: *Я мог бы привести сотни отрывков из книг Грина,
>   **взволнующих** каждого, не потерявшего способности волноваться перед зрелищем прекрасного…* (К. Паустовский); *Валентин поставил ногу так,
>   чтобы она вошла в щель **откроющейся** двери* (В. Франюк). **В
>   подобных случаях следует характеризовать абсолютное время как
>   будущее.**

Comment: Я уверен, что большое число ПБВ вскоре станут обычной, *востребуемой* нормой в РЯ.

Answer (score 0):

От глаголов *добиться, полюбить, сбежать* не образуется причастие действительное причастие настоящего времени. См. в Викисловаре.

Comment: Ваш ответ совершенно непонятен, исправьте его.

Comment: @Tagirix, речь идёт о причастиях будущего времени.

Answer (score -1):

Мне кажется, что в языке **нет потребности в таких причастиях**, так как они обозначают признак предмета, отнесенного к **завершившемуся** действию, а с такой задачей вполне справляются действительные причастия прошедшего времени с суффиксом ВШ, например: (полюбящий) и полюбивший.

Я не очень представляю себе примеры, в которых две эти формы имели бы **разное смысловое значение**, а фонетика у "причастий будущего времени" **не очень удобная** для произношения.

Думаю, что именно вследствие этих причин такие формы употребляются крайне редко и не нормируются в современном языке.

Comment: ПБВ **активно употребляются**, они востребованы в  современном языке и филологи наперебой пишут монографии об этом новостаром грамматическом явлении в РЯ. Язык развивается независимо от мнения кабинетных нормировщиков, не правда ли?

Comment: Дерзкий Grantum, пожалуйста, приведите примеры использования ПБВ у известных писателей (или не очень известных). Также мне хотелось бы на конкретном примере увидеть, что  семантика  двух форм различна, что без ПБВ никак не обойтись. Кабинетные нормировщики мне не нравятся, как и вам, но здесь важно определить действительную необходимость подобных причастий.

Comment: Для начала Гоголь : Мертвые души (1842) 
Другая бумага содержала в себе отношение губернатора
соседственной губернии о убежавшем от законного
преследования разбойнике, и что буде окажется в их
губернии какой подозрительный человек, **не предъявящий
никаких свидетельств и паспортов**, то задержать его
немедленно.

Comment: Почему будущее время недостойно своей причастной формы?? Паустовский : " сотни отрывков из книг Грина, **взволнующих каждого...**

Comment: Здесь замена вполне возможна:  "что буде окажется в их губернии какой подозрительный человек, не предъявивший никаких свидетельств и паспортов, то задержать его немедленно". Можно считать, что деепричастия с суффиксов ВШ - это универсальная форма, обозначающая  признак ЗАВЕРШЕННОГО  действия в любом времени.

Comment: Возможны любые замены в любом тексте. Давайте возьмем известную вещь и позаменяем одни формы на другие. Писатель не обидится!  Вместо голого отрицания новых возможностей языка надо   его, язык, благодарить и пользоваться ими. Зачем нам синонимы, например? Они позволяют ярче, образнее выразить свои впечатления и мысли, скажут нам.  Синонимы употреблять разрешено))) Новые наречия, существительные, прилагательные, иностранные термины - пожалуйста, сколько угодно. ПБВ - вне закона,  они нам не нужны, и так РЯ сложный...

Comment: Нашел по наводке Завады : (из письма Гоголя) "Я 
воображаю, в каком странном недоумении будет потомок наш, **вздумающий искать** нашего общества в 
наших мелодрамах"

Comment: Конструкция : "Багиров рассчитывал, что когда-нибудь он провернет крупное дело, и **в карман ляжет сумма, сделающая его достаточно самостоятельным** и независимым от воли родителей". Попробуйте заменить ПБВ на ППВ) Время описывается будущее : "когда-нибудь провернет, ляжет сумма", но вместо дубового "которая сделает" автор органично употребляет ПБВ ***сделающая***, и против этого возразить нечего.

Comment: Из сети хорошая фраза : *никак не сбегущий беженец*.

Comment: "...и в карман ляжет сумма, сделающая его достаточно самостоятельным и независимым от воли родителей". Здесь, пожалуй, ПБВ НА МЕСТЕ, но на это есть причины: нужно обозначить сдвиг времен: "ляжет сумма, которая сделает".

Comment: Да и во всех приведенных здесь примерах  обоснованность  использования     ПДБ связана именно со сдвигом времени глагола и причастия. В других  случаях использование таких причастий явно не у места, так что необходимо  определенной языковое чутье для использования подобныхконструций.