# Пройдящий мимо, не стесняйся, заходи

Tags: словообразование, деепричастия

А почему, собственно, не существует литературного слово "пройдящий"? 
"Прошедший" есть, но оно немного не так звучит и не всегда уместно.

Например, 
1. Пройдящий задание, получил приз. 
2. Прошедший задание, получил приз.
Первый вариант более реальный что ли по созвучию подготовки к действию. Второй вариант как бы больше говорит, что задание уже сделано!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это (для фразы из заголовка) вопрос о нормативности *причастий будущего времени* (считается, что их не должно быть).

https://school-science.ru/2/10/29951

http://www.emory.edu/INTELNET/prich_bud.htm

Он и здесь рассматривался:

[Причастия будущего времени](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417902/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8)

Если в будущем произойдёт какая-либо легализация таких причастий, то начинать надо с более естественного варианта "**пройдущий**" (значение: тот, который предположительно пройдёт). Слову же "*пройдящий*" если и найдётся какая-то роль, то скорее всего это будет прилагательное вроде "пропащего", обозначающее что-нибудь вроде пройдохи или проходимца.

Comment: Ой, и правда... И здесь тоже. А я не поленился опять эту жвачку переживать. Вопрос-то всплывает на разных ресурсах с пугающей частотой.

Comment: Давно надо легализовать!

Answer (score 1):

На вопрос "почему?" есть только один абсолютно верный ответ. Потому что таких причастий в русском языке **не бывает**.

Есть формы бегущий-бежавший-пробежавший, но нет "пробегущий".  Есть любящий-любивший-полюбивший, но нет "полюбящий". Эти причастия будущего времени встречаются только как окказионализмы, нормативным языком не признаваемые.

> Так вот что ожидает немцев, сейчас пойдущих в атаку, чтобы раздавить
>   один-единственный несчастный эскадрон.

Гумилев, "записки Кавалериста".

Если даже этого недостаточно, то краткая справка. 
Причастия в русском языке бывают прошедшего и настоящего времени.

Если ограничится действительным залогом, то первые образуются из приставочных и (реже) бесприставочных глаголов **совершенного вида** с помощью суффикса "-вш/-ш": *проводивший, забывший, проходивший, решивший, замерзший*. Все такие причастия сохраняют совершенный вид, унаследованный от порождающего глагола.

Вторые, причастия несовершенного времени, образуются от глаголов **несовершенного вида** с помощью суффикса "-ущ"/"-ющ"/"-ащ"/"-ящ":  *летящий, бегущий, решающий, загоняющий, прибирающий* и тех же "-ш"/"-вш": *летевший, бежавший, загнавший, прибравший* и т.д.

"Пройти" - глагол совершенного вида, от него невозможно нормативно образовать причастие с помощью суффикса "-ущ" - это получится этакое "причастие будущего времени", которые в русском отсутствуют.

Можно, конечно, поинтересоваться, почему такая лакуна?! Да скорее всего потому, что эти причастия не нужны. Давным давно подмечено, что современная система видо-временных характеристик русского глдагола тяготеет к не абсолютной временной шкале (прошлое-настоящее-будущее), а к относительной (до-во время-поле того, как). А с этой задачей существующие типы причастий вполне справляются. Что, кстати, видно и на примере классификации самих причастий. Категория вида фактически вытеснила категорию времени, оставшуюся только в традиционных названиях категории причастий (причастия настоящего и прошедшего времени). Хотя классификация по видовому признаку куда актуальнее.

> Первый вариант более реальный что ли по созвучию подготовки к
>   действию. Второй вариант как бы больше говорит, что задание уже
>   сделано!

А вот и нет. Поскольку обе формы порождены глаголами совершенного вида, то задание "уже сделано" в обоих случаях (оставим сейчас вопрос о нормативности первой формы). Только в первом случае "уже сделано в будущем". Это некий аналог английского Future perfect получается. То есть "уже", то это будет потом. Лишний раз говорит, что такая логика русскому языку совсем не свойственна, а формы - лишние.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ, но я не согласен.

Answer (score 1):

**Проходящий мимо, не стесняйся, заходи.**

Проходить ― ***проходящий***. Причастная форма настоящего времени обозначает действие, **одновременное** с действием глагола-сказуемого. Здесь не может быть других вариантов.

Но вот от глагола ***пройти*** можно образовать два причастия: ***прошедший и пройдущий.***

Обычно мы пользуемся формой ***прошедший***, которая обозначает **завершенность** действия вообще, **в том числе в будущем времени**. А нужна ли нам тогда форма ***пройдущий*** (которую  подчеркивает орфографический редактор как нечто ему неизвестное)?

Да, **бывают случаи, когда эта форма вполне уместна**, но применять ее нужно именно **по необходимости**, да и то на свой страх и риск.

**Сравним следующие примеры:**

**1) Видовая ситуация** (второе  действие осуществляется после окончания первого):

Приз получит (будущее время) игрок, успешно **прошедший** все этапы соревнования.

**2) ВременнАя Ситуация** (**требует сдвига по времени в будущем**):

Если сегодня никто **не сможет** (будущее время) получить приз,  то двойной приз  получит **пройдущий**  все этапы соревнования **в следующей игре**.

Если написать ***прошедший все этапы***, то выражение плохо сочетается с прилагательным  ***следующей***. Также обратим внимание на то, что это **субстантивированное причастие**, поэтому его **нельзя заменить** придаточным предложением "который успешно пройдет..".

Впрочем, скорее всего, причастие ***пройдущий*** никто применять не будет, а предложение будет просто усложнено: ...приз  получит тот, кто пройдет все этапы соревнования в следующей игре.

**У Гумилева:**

Так вот что ожидает немцев, **сейчас пойдущих в атаку,** чтобы раздавить один-единственный несчастный эскадрон.

**Здесь уж точно нельзя** написать "сейчас пошедших в атаку", они еще не пошли, действие начнется только в ближайшем будущем.  Можно использовать придаточное предложение "которые сейчас пойдут в атаку", но книжная форма не вписывается в общий стиль "Записок", и автор использует причастие "пойдущих".

**Примечание**

Причастия будущего времени также могут иметь **фонетические ограничения**: не каждое слово удобно для произношения, и даже обычные формы причастий  образуются не от каждого глагола.

Так, в паре ***пойдущий – пройдущий*** первое причастие имеет более приемлемую фонетику и хотя бы какую-то частотность применения (2 примера в Нацкорпусе):

А скоро во вкладных листах «Полезных советов», **пойдущих** для наших подписчиков во все июньские четверги, соединю много вопросов и отвечу обстоятельно каждому подписчику. [В. Ф. Майстрах. П// «Трудовая копейка», 1915]

И если предположить, что применение причастий будущего времени **будет разрешено в грамматике**, но это, скорее всего,  будет касаться далеко не каждого глагола.

Comment: Благодарю, но думаю, такие причастия надо разрешать.

Comment: Такие формы нужны в единичных случаях и вполне могут сойти за авторские грамматические неологизмы. Кто ими будет заниматься?  И потом, у кого Вы собираетесь спрашивать разрешения? Вот у нас имеется Полный академический справочник по орфографии и пунктуации (доступен онлайн), а где такой академический справочник по грамматике? Ну есть еще Полная акцентуированная парадигма по Зализняку, там таких причастий нет.

Comment: Если у кого-то их там нет, это еще не значит, что их не может быть вообще.

Comment: Они могут быть вообще, но они ненормированные, потому что фонетика у них сомнительная, реальная потребность в них мизерная, и их практически всегда можно заменить придаточными определительными. Вот и существует они  в своей нише на правах авторских грамматических неологизмов, там им и место.

Comment: Спасибо, Жасмин, что дали шанс авторам на неологизмы!