# "Обеспечащим" - есть ли такое слово?

Tags: грамотная-речь, причастия, спряжение, времена

> - Информацию в поле адреса отправителя письма следует указывать в порядке, **который обеспечит** правильную обработку письма автоматизированной системой.
> - Информацию в поле адреса отправителя письма следует указывать в порядке, **обеспечащим** правильную обработку письма автоматизированной системой.

Это лишь примеры. Меня интересует слово "обеспечащим". А вообще, есть ли оно? Гугл даёт всего 9 результатов, из которых нет ни одного, ведущего на словарь или сайт о русском языке.

Да, я знаю что есть слово "обеспечивающим". Но это слово, на мой взгляд, указывает на настоящее время, а не будущее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вопрос о допустимости образования **причастий будущего времени** в русском языке. В учебной литературе обычно *отрицают* такую возможность, однако можно встретить дискуссии на эту тему, основывающиеся на случаях употребления таких причастий в художественной и религиозной литературе:
http://www.emory.edu/INTELNET/dar17.html

На форуме эти вопросы тоже обсуждались:
[Причастия будущего времени](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417902/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8)

Answer (score 2):

В языках существуют отчетливые правила правила образования форм, следующие из сочетания букв в слове.
Например, если в языке появляется существительное «гунджуб», то мы знаем, как образовывать формы(я предпочитаю термин «конфигурации») этого слова исходя из сочетаний букв, а не из того, что мы слышали то, как образовываются эти формы; мы понимаем, что чтобы образовать множественную форму, следует добавить «ы» в конец — «гунджубы». Если появляется глагол «бурбувать», то мы знаем, как образовывать причастие — «бурбующий». Если я, как носитель языка, не знаю, что обозначает общеупотребительный глагол в форме причастия «обеспечащим»(я предполагаю, что это причастие, но мне не понятно, совершенное ли это причастие, страдательное ли это причасти, и тп ), то так говорить не следует, так как носители языка не будут понимать вас, или как минимум будут иметь затруднения в понимании.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще вопрос интересный, но я вынужден ограничиться очень краткой справкой – тем более, что @Alex_ander по существу сказал всё и дал ссылку.

Эту форму действительно можно классифицировать как причастия будущего времени, которые не являются сколько-нибудь нормативными в современном русском языке. При этом в качестве этакой поэтической вольности они окказионально используются, и в целом их грамматические категории (время, залог, вид) понятны носителю.

Но тут-то дело в том, что оправданные примеры такого употребления очень редки. Грамматика приведенной в вашем примере фразы **не требует** будущего времени, оно вообще там непонятно. Там вполне по контексту – обычное причастие настоящего времени ("обеспечивающем").

Таким образом, вероятнее всего данный пример – просто опечатка.

Гугл находит как минимум один пример, где такое использование по крайней мере понятно.

> Только женская половина считает ребенка чем-то особенным, фактором,
> обеспечащим ей какое-нибудь будущее.

Разумеется, речь не идет о нормативности такого использования, но здесь действительно понятно будущее время. Вариант замены – *"фактором, который обеспечит (в будущем)"*.

Подробнее я писал тут:
[Пройдящий мимо, не стесняйся, заходи](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/442992)

Comment: Нельзя что-то классифицировать, как грамматическую категорию, пока это не стало частью языка, пока множество людей не используют эту форму в своей речи. В качестве поэтической вольности можно вообще все что-угодно коверкать и как-угодно.

Comment: «Обеспечивающим хорошую жизнь» — все поймут, «обеспечившим хорошую жизнь» — все поймут, «обеспечиваемый хорошей жизнью» — все поймут, «обеспеченный хорошей жизнью» — все поймут, «обеспечащим хорошую жизнь» — только бехемотус поймет.

Comment: @JimKorbett извините, вы избрали неприемлемый тон.