# «В порядке, обеспечивающим...» Или обеспечивающем?

Tags: грамматика, согласование, выбор-варианта, типы-ошибок

Как пишется: *в порядке обеспечивающ**им*** или *в порядке обеспечивающ**ем***?

Я искал через Гугл, и оба написания используются как в книгах, так и в законах и официальных документах.

Вот пара примеров:

> Статистическая информация закрытого характера представляется органам государственной статистики в порядке, **обеспечивающим** сохранение государственной и военной тайны. (http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_885/dce376b9f664ba962b2c3f837bec90fed5bd3e6c/)

> Государственное или муниципальное унитарное предприятие вправе осуществить возмездное отчуждение недвижимого имущества, принадлежащего ему и арендуемого лицом, отвечающим требованиям, предусмотренным статьей 3 настоящего Федерального закона, в порядке, **обеспечивающем** реализацию преимущественного права арендатора на приобретение указанного имущества. (https://base.garant.ru/12161610/741609f9002bd54a24e5c49cb5af953b/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В порядке (в чём?) — предложный падеж;
в порядке (каком?) — [обеспечивающ**ем**](http://xn----8sbfkarmiepbjh5aj.xn--p1ai/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9/).

В первом предложении имеется *грамматическая ошибка* (то есть ошибка в выборе формы слова). Правильно:
*органам* статистики, *обеспечивающим*;
органам статистики *в порядке, обеспечивающем*.

Если все-таки предположить, что причастие относится к слову "органам", то получается такое предложение (упрощаем): *информация представляется органам статистики в порядке, обеспечивающим сохранение тайны.*
Смысл получается таким: информацию даем только органам в порядке, а тем органам, которые не в порядке, — не даем. Такая трактовка маловероятна.

Вот еще [пример](https://files.stroyinf.ru/Data1/46/46753/index.htm) ошибочного написания:

> 5.1. Обмен данными геоэкологического мониторинга между участниками мониторинга осуществляется в соответствии с настоящим регламентом на безвозмездной основе, а также с учетом требований режима секретности в порядке, обеспечивающим сохранение государственной и служебной тайны.

Здесь могло быть так:
с учетом требований ***режима*** секретности, ***обеспечивающего*** (Р. п.);
с учетом ***требований*** режима секретности, ***обеспечивающих*** (Р. п.);
с учетом требований режима секретности ***в порядке, обеспечивающем*** (П. п.).

P. S. О грамматике и орфографии: неправильный выбор падежа относится к [грамматическим ошибкам](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Answer (score 2):

"Обеспечивающем" и "обеспечивающим" - это разные падежи, никаким образом не не взаимозаменяемые.

Конкретно по примерам. В обоих случаях должно быть **"в порядке, обеспечивающем"**.
В первом примере (как он у вас представлен) - очевидная ошибка.
Конечно, речь идет не о передаче (кому?) "органам обеспечивающим" (ибо это требует совершенно фантастического контекста уже потому, что эти функции вне компетенции органов государственной статистики), а о "порядке, обеспечивающем" (предл. падеж).

Comment: Бегемотус, а вот [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/466742) у вас написание через букву "и". Это не опечатка? :-)

Comment: @jsv Спасибо. Это ошибка.  Объяснимая (ушел от контекста), но непростительная. Исправил. *Но будет и пожелание. Такие вещи лучше сообщать в теме, к которой они относятся.* То есть там, где ошибка сделана. Бустрее понимаешь, о чем речь.

Answer (score 0):

Все верно. Все зависит от того, к кому слову относится причастие.

Статистическая информация закрытого характера представляется органам(каким? — тв.пад.) государственной статистики в порядке, обеспечивающИм....

Государственное или муниципальное унитарное предприятие вправе осуществить возмездное отчуждение недвижимого имущества, принадлежащего ему и арендуемого лицом, отвечающим требованиям, предусмотренным статьей 3 настоящего Федерального закона, в порядке(в чем? — пред.пад)обеспечивающЕм...

Comment: Не согласен с первым пунктом. Там не "органам, обеспечивающим", а "в порядке, обеспечивающем". Это просто ошибка.

Comment: @grizzly, представляется (кем?) органом в порядке.      Остальное является определением к слову орган. А во втором случае, действительно, причастие зависит от слова "в порядке".

Comment: Серж, "в порядке" не имеет самостоятельного смысла. В самом документе этой ошибки нет: https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=d87rAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA6-PA5&img=1&pgis=1&dq=%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5,-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U0RWjg3aAaThT0vY1r9cz-twbN0xQ&edge=0

Comment: @Alex_ander, ваша ссылка не открывается.

Comment: К какому слову тогда во втором предложении относится причастие?

Comment: К слову "порядок" (в каком порядке?) - в обоих предложениях. Книга: Вестник статистики, вып. 6-12 1992, с.5

Comment: Alex_andex, сперва вы пишете, что слово порядок не имеет самостоятельного смысла, а потом пишете, что причастие относится к этому слову.

Comment: @Серж В ответе у Вас написано: *органам - творит. падеж*. Здесь дательный (кому?). В обоих случаях идет предложный падеж: *в порядке (каком?), обеспечивающЕм*.

Comment: @Alex_ander ссылка-то открывается, но она не атрибутирована. Хорошо бы ***сразу*** давать ссылку на сам документ, коли уж вы его нашли (вы дали его в другом комментарии - уже пост-фактум).