# Правильно ли построено предложение? (2)

Tags: грамматика

> Тренер пообещал исключить из команды игроков, сыгравших плохо в предстоящем матче.

Правильно ли построено предложение? Если нет, то в чем ошибка?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это д/з.

Comment: Мы не выполняем д/з, но можем помочь и поправить, если вы дополните вопрос своими рассуждениями.

Comment: Ну то что это д/з - спорно.

Comment: @Evgeny все ответы должны давать в ответах.

Answer (score 2):

Предложение  постороено неправильно: ошибка в употреблении причастного оборота.

У причастий нет формы будущего времени, поэтому, видимо, автор предложения использует форму прошедшего. Но речь в предложении идёт о событиях, которые произойдут в будущем.

Необходимо придумать синтаксический синоним, заменив, например, причастный оборот на придаточное определительное:***Тренер пообещал исключить из команды игроков, которые плохо сыграют в предстоящем матче.***

Или местоименно-определительное: ***Тренер пообещал исключить из команды тех игроков, которые плохо сыграют в предстоящем матче.***

Comment: Любопытно, как по разному мы с вами поняли смысл изначальной фразы. Мне показалось, что имелись в виду игроки, которые уже сыграли плохо в неком уже состоявшемся матче. А вы исходили из того, что речь об игроках, которые плохо сыграют в предстоящем матче. Интересно, что же имела в виду сама автор вопроса?

Answer (score 2):

*Тренер пообещал исключить из команды игроков, сыгравших плохо в предстоящем матче.*

Здесь надо бы употребить **причастие будущего времени** "сыграющих", но таких причастий вроде бы не существует (хотя потребность в них есть).

Обсуждение вопроса: [Причастия будущего времени](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417902/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8)  [Достижимый,постижимый - какие это причастия?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416950/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F/419203#419203)  И др.

В приведенном предложении использовано **причастие прошедшего времени**, а это неверно.

Тогда приходится заменять причастный оборот придаточным предложением, хотя это книжная и более сложная конструкция:

*Тренер пообещал исключить из команды игроков, которые плохо сыграют в предстоящем матче.
Тренер пообещал исключить из команды игроков, которые будут плохо играть в предстоящем матче.*

Answer (score 1):

Можно, конечно, внести некоторую ясность в сказанное, добавив одну запятую:

> Тренер пообещал исключить из команды игроков, сыгравших плохо, в предстоящем матче.

Тогда становится понятно, что игроки сыграли плохо не в предстоящем матче, а в принципе сыграли плохо (когда-то там).
Но лучше немного изменить порядок слов, чтобы фраза легче воспринималась:

> Игроков, сыгравших плохо, тренер пообещал исключить из команды в предстоящем матче.

А еще лучше - написать так:

> Игроков, сыгравших плохо, тренер пообещал отстранить от участия в предстоящем матче.

Comment: "исключить из команды в предстоящем матче" — так не говорят. Исключают из команды насовсем, а не на один матч. А так было бы верно. Я считаю, что здесь имелось в виду рассогласование времён: "сыгравших в предстоящем", которое можно исправить разными способами.

Comment: @grizzly, вы абсолютно правы. Я просто попытался ограничиться изменением порядка слов в предложении, не заменяя сами слова. Безусловно, вариант "отстранить от участия в предстоящем матче" был бы предпочтительнее.

Comment: Теперь согласен (и я тоже предполагал в том числе такой вариант).