# Можно говорить "будущих делать"?

Tags: выбор-слов

...людей в целом неплохих, но абсолютно неизвестных и реально вряд ли что-либо будущих делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. О причастиях будущего времени**

Тема причастий будущего времени весьма актуальна, она активно обсуждается в Сети, например:

[http://daschess.wiki-wiki.ru/daschess/index.php/Причастие_будущего_времени_в_русском_языке](http://daschess.wiki-wiki.ru/daschess/index.php/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5)

**Но нужны ли такие причастия?** Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, рассмотрим два предложения:

(1) Храбрец, **сумеющий** победить дракона, получит в награду принцессу.

(2) Храбрец, **сумевший** победить дракона, получит в награду принцессу.

В первом предложении оба действия отнесены к будущему и происходят в определенной последовательности, а во втором **всё очень неясно.** Возможно, дракон уже побежден, а церемония награждения вот-вот состоится.

Из этого можно сделать вывод, что строгий литературный язык не совсем справедлив к причастиям будущего времени и иногда без них трудно обходиться.

**2) Ответ на вопрос**

***...людей в целом неплохих, но абсолютно неизвестных и реально вряд ли что-либо будущих делать.***

А вот конкретная форма "люди, будущие делать" мне кажется **некорректной.**

Глагол ***быть*** используется в качестве вспомогательного глагола для образования сложного будущего времени, и **причастная форма** такого глагола выглядит по меньшей мере странной.

Коме того, существует форма ***будущий***, которая может быть прилагательным или субстантивированным существительным. Соответственно, возникают естественные трудности в различении  всех этих форм и в понимании текста.

Поэтому лучше использовать **придаточное определительное предложение:**

*..людей в целом неплохих, но абсолютно неизвестных, **которые вряд ли что-либо будут делать.***

Comment: Sharon, у вас обе ссылки ведут на один и тот же текст (весьма сомнительного, кстати, качества).

Comment: У меня вроде бы одна ссылка.  Мне показалось, что она не хуже и не лучше других. Приведена просто в качестве примера того, что тема обсуждается, но не более того.

Comment: *У меня вроде бы одна ссылка* - тогда пардон... Выглядела как две разных. Насчет "не лучше других" - это я к слову сказал. Но если уж на то пошло, она безымянна и в свою очередь ни на кого не ссылается.

Comment: А вот к вам у меня вопрос. *А вот конкретная форма "люди, будущие делать" мне кажется некорректной.* Вы действительно не видите, что "будущих" сюда попало не просто так, а для образования формы будущего времени. от глагола **несовершенного** вида. Поэтому все ваши отсылки и противопоставления теряют актуальность.

Comment: Я свой ответ разделила на две части. В первой части говорится о причастиях будущего времени в общем плане. К самому вопросу эта часть прямого отношения не имеет. Во второй части я разбираю заданное предложение. Насколько я понимаю, сложное будущее время образуется только от глаголов несовершенного вида, не видеть этого как бы нельзя. Но именно такая форма причастия будущего времени кажется мне  некорректной, и я предлагаю заменить ее придаточным предложением, в котором будет обозначено незавершенное действие (будут делать). К сожалению, в литературе мне не встречалось обсуждение таких форм.

Answer (score 3):

В строгом литературном языке — нет. В академических грамматиках причастия будущего времени не фиксируются.
Причем это касается не только подобной аналитической формы ("будущий делать") но и синтетической ("сделающий"). Несмотря на подобный запрет, такие формы спорадически присутствуют в современных текстах, можно предположить, что на каком-то этапе развития языка они были более активны и вполне естественны.

О синтетических немножко есть тут: [Достижимый,постижимый - какие это причастия?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416950) (в ответах).  Что касается рассматриваемой аналитической формы (для глаголов несовершенного вида), то грамматически их невозможность определяется тем, что слово "будущий" здесь выступает в качестве причастия, а в современном языке оно стало де-факто только прилагательным. Хотя лично у меня обе эти формы неприятия не вызывают, особенно первая. Она понятна и естественна и — на мое восприятие — внутренней логике языка не противоречит.

Comment: Заменил в последнем предложении "они" на "она" (иначе предложение было несогласованно). Или имелось в виду наоборот?

Comment: @grizzly - все правильно, спасибо.

Comment: Достижимый и постижимый причастия БУДУЩЕГО времени?!

Comment: @Горевант да нет, Господь с Вами. Это автору вопроса такое привиделось. Это вряд ли причастия - и уж менее всего время будущее. Но вообще вопрос образования причастий и их отличия от прилагатьельных сам по себе интересный...Задайте отдельный вопрос, здесь, наверное, не стоит комментарии перегружать посторонними сведениями.

Answer (score -1):

ДА можно так говорить!!! (И так глагол делать ну и сделать!!! НУ-С начнём!!!)
1). Делать.
Прошедшее время:
Действительное - Делавший;
Страдательное - Деланный;
Настоящее время (Или же Текущее или Нынешнее):
Действительное - Делающий;
Страдательное - Делаемый;
Будущее время (Или же Сбудущееся):
Действительное - Будущий Делать;
Страдательное - Будущий(ся) Делать(ся) ИЛИ ЖЕ Будемый Делать(ся?);
2]. Сделать.
Прошедшее время:
Действительное - Сделавший;
Страдательное - Сделанный;
?Настоящее время (Или же ?Текущее или ?Нынешнее):
?Действительное - Сущий Сделать(ся);
?Страдательное - Сомый Делать(ся);
Будущее время (Или же Сбудущееся):
Действительное - Сделающий;
Страдательное - Сделаемый;